# Calling Web-Site in background when accessing another

Tags: javascript, html

I have been using a product which displays parsed XML files as HTML. It provides functionality to edit the XML within the product and refreshes its internal cache automatically.
However if you edit the XML from outside the product it will not reload the changed XML and so the changes are not visible.
To reload the XML (the product is Splunk btw) you need to append;

> en-US/debug/refresh?entity=/admin/views

to the end of the IP/Host of the server. Is there a method through either HTML or JavaScript where I could call this URL in the background when a page is loaded?
Running a script externally fails as it requires credentials to access and hard-coding them isn't an option.

If I could call the page from within a user session already in existence then it would reload the cache transparently to the user.

Comment: Is that page is on the same domain?

Comment: Yes, all pages that the users access as well as the refresh URL are all hosted on the same server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML is static, so it doesn't do anything once it's loaded and rendered. You can use javascript though. I'd recommend using jQuery, since it makes writing javascript very easy, but if you rather not use any javascript libraries, you could copy quirksmode's XMLHttpRequest function for loading xml dynamically:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html

Comment: Its not actually XML I am looking to load, all I need to do is to call another page on the same site in the background whilst not displaying it. Is this something that jQuery can achieve? I've been looking through the documentation but I cannot see how it would let me do this transparently in the background

Comment: Yeah, you can do that with jQuery. Check out api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/, api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and  api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.